# Powershell Hashtable - Access outer object in nested script block

Tags: powershell

If I have a powershell hash object, thus:

```
$hash = @{
             Prop1 = "Hello";
             Prop2 = "Goodbye";
             ArbitraryScriptBlock = { Do-Things -SomeParameter ThisHashTable?}
         }
```

I want to pass the entire value of `$hash` to the `Do-Things` function, more or less analogous to passing `this` as an argument to a method in C#:

```
 var results = DoThings(this);
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. Just pass in parameters to the script block and use the `$args` array to get the argument, like so:

```
$hash = @{
             Prop1 = "Hello";
             Prop2 = "Goodbye";
             ArbitraryScriptBlock = { Write-Host $args[0].Prop1 }
         }

$hash.ArbitraryScriptBlock.Invoke($hash)
```

I usually prefer specifying the parameters my functions and script blocks take as input, which would look similar to:

```
$hash = @{
             Prop1 = "Hello";
             Prop2 = "Goodbye";
             ArbitraryScriptBlock = { PARAM( $this ) Write-Host $this.Prop1 }
         }

$hash.ArbitraryScriptBlock.Invoke($hash)
```

Note: The `$this` variable name is not anything special and you can name it anything you want to.

You could also use the `&` call operator to execute the script block, which also lets you call the script block providing a nice familiar syntax:

```
$hash = @{
            Prop1 = "Hello";
            Prop2 = "Goodbye";
            ArbitraryScriptBlock = { PARAM( $ParamName ) Write-Host $ParamName.Prop1 }
        }

& $hash.ArbitraryScriptBlock $hash
# Or, perhaps even nicer:
& $hash.ArbitraryScriptBlock -ParamName $hash
```

I suggest reading up on the help section about script blocks, which you can get by calling `Get-Help about_Script_Blocks`.

Comment: Yep, perfect - no idea how I didn't get this. Thanks Robert.

Comment: If the script block uses CmdletBinding, you should the invocation operator instead:  & $hash.ArbitraryScriptBlock $hash

Comment: I've added using the `&` call operator to the answer. Thanks!